# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element "pasja"

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I know that there are plenty of similar posts but I tried those advices and they don't work in my case : (.
This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pasja>
<gitara>
<typ>klasyczna</typ>
<struny>nylonowe</struny>
<cena>500</cena>
<gryf>szeroki</gryf>
<muzyka>klasyczna i flamenco</muzyka>
</gitara>

</pasja>
```

And here's my Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

<xs:element name="pasja" type="pas"/>


<xs:complexType name="pas">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="gitara">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="typ" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="struny" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="cena" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="gryf" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="muzyka" type="xs:string"/>  
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

validator:http://xmltools.corefiling.com/miniSchemaValidate/Controller
I get this error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element "pasja"
I really need help !

Comment: I am not sure whether its copy paste error but the xml doesn't start with <pasja> element , hence adding it before <gitara> will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, paste error, thanks! :)) I repaired it

Comment: So its an copy paste error here or does the actual xml doesnt have this declaration since looking at the error it also points to the same.

Comment: xml has this declaration (I cut it off while copying :-)  ) and I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Does the error says which line and column where the error occured ?

Comment: It says:
TYPE    LOC MESSAGE
Validation 2,8 cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration
So i guess lines 2 and 8?

Comment: type="pas" , what is this if this is not needed can you remove this and check ? also with xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd".

Comment: type="pas" is the name of complexType I defined a few lines later.
After removing xmlns="tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"; xmlns:mstns="tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd";. there are more errors

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the namespace declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pasja xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
   <gitara>
      <typ>klasyczna</typ>
      <struny>nylonowe</struny>
      <cena>500</cena>
      <gryf>szeroki</gryf>
      <muzyka>klasyczna i flamenco</muzyka>
   </gitara>
</pasja>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema to

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="pasja" type="pas"/>


    <xs:complexType name="pas">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="gitara">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="typ" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="struny" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="cena" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="gryf" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="muzyka" type="xs:string"/>  
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    </xs:schema>
```